# SQL JOIN to get two records for each row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, transactions

I have two tables, say

> TABLE: Transactions
>
> COLUMNS: sender_id, receiver_id, value

and

> TABLE: Users
>
> COLUMNS: user_id, username

Is it possible to make a SQL statement to JOIN two rows from the users table for each record in the transactions table? So for each result row, I should have two usernames from the users table, but with two different aliases. How to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: At the very least provide sample data and the desired output.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. However you have to show research yourself. So get a bit better information and an example in here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Full Outer Join in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql)

Comment: didn't add sample data because I thought the table/field names would be intuitive enough on what i wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `sender_id` and `receiver_id` are references to a `user_id`, and assuming that `user_id` is UNIQUE in the `Users` table... yes.

Join to the `Users` table twice.

For example:

```
  SELECT t.sender_id
       , t.receiver_id
       , t.value
       , s.user_id   AS sender_user_id
       , s.username  AS sender_username
       , r.user_id   AS receiver_user_id
       , r.username  AS receiver_username
    FROM `Transactions` t
    LEFT
    JOIN `Users` s ON s.user_id = t.sender_id 
    LEFT
    JOIN `Users` r ON r.user_id = t.receiver_id
   ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

The query is using outer joins... the row from `Transactions` will be returned if `receiver_id` or `sender_id` doesn't match a row in the `Users` table.

The keyword `LEFT` can be removed to change that behavior, so a row will be returned only if there is a matching row in `Users` for both `sender_id` and `receiver_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, by talking about aliases.  You need two joins:

```
select us.username, ur.username, t.value
from transactions t left join
     users us
     on t.sender_id = us.user_id left join
     users ur
     on t.receiver_id = ur.receiver_id;
```

`left join` is just in case one of the values does not match.